# For Ruby on Rails, how to show for Product Management to see the time it takes to render the page, right on the page itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know from the server log (or the console output), that the time to show the page can be seen.  But what about just **for product manager** to see real time how much time it takes to render a page?  (also for easy to see for the developer)

I tried using at the very beginning of the controller's action

```
@time_start = Time.now
```

and at the end of view application layout, show

```
Time.now - @time_start
```

actually, it is kind of close... about 3% to 5% off only.  But is there a way to show as close as possible, or even somehow show what the server log is showing?

For example, is there a @time_start that Rails keep as the very beginning even before it does any routing?  Maybe a timestamp the moment the request is received by the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I suggest checking out an enterprise Rails benchmarking solution, such as [New Relic](http://support.newrelic.com/kb/docs/developer-mode) (it's free in development mode!).

However if you want to do it for yourself, I would suggest tapping into the Middleware and time it there.

This should get you started:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware

Answer (score 1):

New relic has a developer mode that will give you insight to the time it takes to render a page

- http://support.newrelic.com/kb/docs/developer-mode
- https://github.com/newrelic/rpm

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this impossible to do in a single pass - by definition!  You can't ever render the *full* amount of time it's taken to render a page to the page itself, because that page, obviously, is still getting rendered.

If you want to be super-precise, you'll probably have to cache the full render time (in the session, maybe?) and fetch it with JS.  Or you could show it on the *next* page, but that might be confusing.

If you want to come as close as you can, but don't want to bother with the above, then I'd recommend putting your `<%= @start_time - Time.now %>` line towards the end of your *layout* - things like the [content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) helper imply that the layout is actually rendered *after* the page template.

Hope this helps!